# How to validate a new measurement tool?

Tags: validation, measurement, agreement-statistics

I want to test whether the results obtained from a new sensor agree with those of an already used more accurate sensor. Both sensors measure a certain physical quantity which after a transformation can take on values between 0 and 1. These values are then assign to one of three groups so that I have *ordinal* data.

I am going to start an experiment in which I will measure concurrently with both sensors and now face the problem of how to quantify the agreement between those two. I think this problem can be seen as one of interrater agreement and therefore Cohen's kappa can be used.

On the other hand I know that the sensor already in use can measure much more accurate than the new one. It is sort of the *gold standard* at the moment, albeit I know of certain measurement difficulties which make it not a 'perfect' measurement tool. From that point of view I think this is a problem of concurrent validity. However I am not sure which statistical test to use in this case. I've read about using correlation measurements but given that the two sensors measure the exact same thing the should be correlated. Yet, this says nothing about the bias.

Comment: I think that given that you have data from one instrument thought to be a gold standard, this is clearly a question of concurrent validity. What's not entirely clear is what it is you don't know. Do you not know how to establish concurrent validity, or do you know how to do it but you're not sure about the specific statistical test for your data?

Comment: @Ian_Fin Please see my edits.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer to understanding what the question is about, but what is the bias that you talk about right at the end?

Comment: I think the possible differences in values obtained from both sensors have two sources. (1) A random normally distributed error and (2) a systematic error, e.g. one sensors has a tendency to measure values 5% higher than the other. I would refer to the latter as bias.

Comment: Such a bias isn't typically a consideration for validity. An instrument could arguably be perfectly valid while being biased. If your interest is really in establishing and quantifying this bias, rather than merely showing your instrument is measuring what it purports to measure (what we consider as validity) then you will probably need to edit the question to say more about the process of getting from the initial measurement to the ordinal variable.